# Entropy change as temperature changes under isobaric conditions

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

everybody:

I have this question that is definitely a challenge for me and I was looking for some help. I did manage to do part a but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Part b is even harder for me. I'm not sure how to answer that question. From what I know, higher temperature should mean higher entropy but I actually did put the numbers into the equation that I used for a and the answer for it is lower. I'm not sure what's going on.

I hope my work is clear to follow. If not, let me know politely and I will clear things up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have to use absolute temperatures, not centigrade.

Comment: Ok I can fix that but what about part b? You have any comments about that?

Comment: Hint: What is the relation of dS and dQ ?

Comment: @Poutnik dS = dQ/T

Comment: Do not stay at that, apply it in your mind. You know from school that for 2  same numbers, the one divided by the bigger number gives a smaller rusult.

Comment: I'm thinking lower if I simply apply 75 in the denominator. It makes the ratio smaller as opposed to 50.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the same since entropy is a state function?

Comment: What is the average absolute temperature over each of the changes?

Comment: @ChetMiller 285.65

Comment: Temperature difference is not a state.

Comment: I was talking about entropy when I brought up state functions.

Comment: I asked for the average temperature over each of the changes.

Comment: @ChetMiller ((25+50)/2)= 37.5 and ((50+75)/2)=62.5

Comment: @ChetMiller So just plug those values in for T and compare?

Comment: So if you approximate the entropy change as the amount of heat divided by the average absolute temperature, and the amounts of heat are the same, which entropy change is larger?

Comment: The 2 to 50 range would be larger. Ok, that makes sense. I'm not sure how he expected us to not calculate and answer that.

Comment: Note that T in thermodynamics means absolute temperature, not temperature of Celsius nor Fahrenheit scale.

Comment: Again,  school math, the same number divided by bigger number .... You need not to calculate anything.  Is dQ/T1 > dQ/T2 if T1 < T2 ?

Comment: You just did do it without calculating it.  Now confirm it with the accurate calculation.

Answer (score 1):

For part (b), you can approach the problem generally, noting that since for a reversible isobaric process $$dS = \frac{dq_p}{T}= \frac{C_pdT}{T}$$ an equal change in temperature dT will result in a smaller change in entropy dS at higher T assuming constant $C_p$.

You might also proceed as follows. The difference in entropy changes for the first and second steps is

$$\Delta S(T_1 \rightarrow T_2) -\Delta S(T_2 \rightarrow T_3)=C_p\log\left(\frac{T_2}{T_1}\right)-C_p\log\left(\frac{T_3}{T_2}\right)\\=C_p\log\left(\frac{T_2^2}{T_1T_3}\right)\\=C_p\log\left(\frac{T_2^2}{(T_2-\Delta T)(T_2+\Delta T)}\right)\\=C_p\log\left(\frac{T_2^2}{T_2^2-\Delta T^2}\right)\\=-C_p\log\left(1-(\Delta T/T_2)^2\right)$$ Then since $(\Delta T/T_2)^2>0$ it follows that $\Delta S(T_1 \rightarrow T_2) -\Delta S(T_2 \rightarrow T_3)>0$,
which means the entropy change for the first step is greater than for the second.